# How to define a layer only for training phase in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I wanted to know if it's possible to define a layer (convolution, element-wise summation, etc.) only for the training phase in TensorFlow.

For example, I want to have an element-wise summation layer in my network only for the training phase and I want to ignore this layer in the test phase.

This is easily doable in Caffe, I wanted to know if it's possible to do so in TensorFlow as well.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do this with the "tf.cond" control_flow operation.  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#cond

Comment: Thanks. But what should I put in "pred" argument to separate train phase from test phase?

Comment: According to the documentation: A scalar determining whether to return the result of fn1 or fn2. ;)

In this case, I think you can supply the train_phase tensor. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a boolean placeholder with tf.cond().
Just like this:

```
train_phase = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [])
x = tf.constant(2)
def f1(): return tf.add(x, 1)
def f2(): return tf.identity(x)
r = tf.cond(train_phase, f1, f2)
sess.run(r, feed_dict={train_phase: True})  # training phase, r = tf.add(x, 1) = x + 1
sess.run(r, feed_dict={train_phase: False})  # testing phase, r = tf.identity(x) = x
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this by `if`

```
Train = False

x = tf.constant(5.)
y = x + 1
if Train:
    y = y + 2
y = y + 3

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(y) # 11 if Train else 9
```